# Keep class active when clicking another url, jquery

Tags: jquery

Im experimenting a bit with jquery and having a big problem which i have been trying to solve for the past day with google but not sure how to figure it out.

I use a index.php page with a simple php script to retrieve my content from a db, i use links like: `index.php?title=abou`t (example). I found a small jquery script that adds a class active to the `<li>` you click on, this works perfect if the url is (`#about`), it keeps the class active until other link is clicked. but if its an url like "`index.php?title=about`" its removes the active class.

This is my css / html and jquery, my question is how do i keep the button active when its being clicked.

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .nav li { list-style: none; cursor:pointer; }
    .nav li a { display: block; width: 279px; height: 30px;}
    .nav-home { background: url(img/home.png); width: 279px; height: 27px; }
    .nav-home.active, .nav-home:hover { background: url(img/home_1.png); width: 279px;          height: 27px;}
    .nav-video { background: url(img/video.png); width: 279px; height: 27px; }
    .nav-video.active, .nav-video:hover { background: url(img/video_1.png); width: 279px; height: 27px;}
    .nav-contact { background: url(img/contact.png); width: 279px; height: 27px; }
    .nav-contact.active, .nav-contact:hover { background: url(img/contact_1.png); width: 279px; height: 27px;}
    </style>
```

html and jquery:

```
    <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-home"><a href="index.php?title=home"></a></li>
    <li class="nav-video"><a href="index.php?title=video"></a></li>
    <li class="nav-contact"><a href="index.php?title=contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.nav li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
    </script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, kinds regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load a new page, you won't get track of previous client side interactions.

You have to give the `active` class in php, or either parse current `window.location`, get the `title` value and select `<li>` element according to this.

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried and this is working, this is probably far from perfect but does what i want to do : <li <?php if ($title=="home") echo " class=\"nav-home active\""; else echo " class=\"nav-home\""; ?>><a href="index.php?title=home"></a></li> , if you have anything to add please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moonwave99 is correct. And if you want to do this, there are 2 possibilities, 1) you need to put the content of the 3 pages in the single page and just you need to use show() and hide jquery functions or display (block, none) property. 2) while you sending the request to the server, you are sending the title in the query string. By this query string, you need to check and give the class name 'active' where ever you want.

```
eg:  

request URL: -url-?title=a

<a href='url?title=a' <?php if($_GET['title'] == 'a') echo 'active';?>>a</a>
<b href='url?title=b'>b</b>
<c href='url?title=c'>c</c>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this php code before `$(".nav li").click(`

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET["title"]) ) {
    ?>
    $(".nav-"+$_GET["title"])
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('active');
<?}?>
```